# POST to local json file without server, using Svelte and Routiify

Tags: json, svelte, routify

Im writing an PWA in Svelte with Routify and im trying to save notes (containing id, title and a body) in a local json file.

Ive been following this code from Svelte REPL ([Svelte POST example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c62df203051345bfab6aaa4350faf8f4?version=3.20.1)), but they use an web URL. When trying to use a direct link i get a 404, even tho the path is correct.

```
<script>
    let foo = 'title'
    let bar = 'body'
    let result = null
    
    async function doPost () {
        const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                foo,
                bar
            })
        })
        
        const json = await res.json()
        result = JSON.stringify(json)
    }
</script>


<input bind:value={foo} />
<input bind:value={bar} />
<button type="button" on:click={doPost}>
    <p>Post it.</p>
</button>
<p>Result:</p>
<pre>
{result}
</pre>
```

I installed a json server plugin, which kinda worked, but i want to store the data as a local file.

Is it possible to write, using POST to a local json file without using any server?
Is it possible to use relative path when using fetch? Or should i use something else?

Comment: What do you mean by direct link? And could you share your code? The REPL is nice for reference but your own implementation is a bit more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't POST data anywhere else but to a server. Having said that, if you absolutely want to save your data using POST, you can add a serviceworker to your app that intercepts the `fetch()` request and then saves the data in cache, indexeddb, localstorage or something like this. But having that serviceworker in between just for that is a bit silly, you should rather store the data directly in cache, indexeddb or localstorage.

Example for localstorage:

```
const data = { someKey: { someOtherKey: 'some value' } };
localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Be aware though that, no matter which kind of storage you're using, they all might be wiped out if the user decides to clear browser data or if the browser cleans up by itself due to storage shortage.